# ASP.Net MVC: Change ViewData in Child Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, children

I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@ViewData["PageTitle"]</title>
```

I then have a Child Action that is called, and I want to be able to set change this value in that controller action.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the parent context. In your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<title>@ViewContext.ViewData["PageTitle"]</title>
```

and in your child action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["PageTitle"] = "foo";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was nearly there but was missing the @ViewContext bit :-)